# Microsoft Power BI desktop — columns col1 and col2 (from excel) make a chart with col2 y axis vs col1 axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-powerbi, data-visualization

Microsoft Power BI desktop -- after importing excel columns col1 and col2 make a chart with col2 (y-axis) vs col1 (x-axis). Very much like the title says, after importing a spreadsheet from excel, which I can do successfully, I want to make col2 the y-axis and col-1 the x-axis. Assuming they have the same number of rows, which they do, this should be fairly trivial. However, Power BI plots them jointly on the y-axis, instead of in y vs x format. There are various pre-defined templates, but I want to do this without such a template.

For a stacked column chart, I am getting date-columns to work as x-axis, but if I want to do a plot with a non-date column, they all show up on 1 or more y-axis.

For the scatter plot mentioned in the accepted.  answer below,  I can set the columns as axis.  This works, the Fields Section of the Visualization pane should not be confused (as I initially did) with the separate Fields pane.
I am completely new to Microsoft Power BI, but have a long software-development background.

This version (superuser) of the question has now been edited and answered.  This question was originally **copied** from **my own** StackOverflow question which I have since deleted:  The URL *may* still be available to certain moderators, etc:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64562757/microsoft-power-bi-desktop-columns-col1-and-col2-from-excel-make-a-chart-wi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are trying to build a Scatter chart?

If so, then for the scenario you described you probably want to turn off the automatic summerization.

In the **VISUALIZATIONS** pane, **Fields** section, right-click the **X Axis** entry (col1) and choose **Don't summarize**.  Repeat for the **Y Axis** (col2).

If my guesses are off, post more info on what you have tried so far.

Comment: For the scatter plot mentioned in this answer,  I can set the columns as axis.  This works, the Fields Section of the Visualization pane should not be confused (as I initially did) with the separate Fields pane.